# UIView factory creation process

Tags: ios, uiview, delegates, factory

I have a view that will draw a chart ... there are going to be more than one chart type ... How do I wrap them in a factory class? So I have a `MyChart` class (`UIView` subclass)... and if the user can do something like :

```
MyChart *chart = [[Mychart alloc] initWithFrame:frame andType:1];
```

and chart will actually become a `MyLineChart` object ... or some other object that myChart can create? 
Do I just create thouse views in the init  of the myChart class .. and return them in stead of returning self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo code like this

```
typedef enum {
    MyChartTypeLine,
    MyChartTypePoint,
    ...
} MyChartType;

MyLineChart *chart = [MyChart chartWithType:MyChartTypeLine];
```

in MyChart.m add a class method:

```
+ (id)chartWithType:(MyChartType)type
{
    switch (type) {
        case MyChartTypeLine:
            return [[MyLineChart alloc] init];
        case...
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: in the if ... could I do : MyChartType1 *v = [[Mycharttype1 alloc] init]; and then return v ... instead of self ????